# Optional Joda DateTime type field with JSR 303 Validation and Spring converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jodatime, bean-validation

I have a custom parameter converter  & Jackson mapper to handle Joda `DateTime` on Spring controllers input.

The problem is, that server gives `400 Bad Request` if date is given in bad format, because of `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by Joda formatter during conversion.

I could make converter to return null on failing conversion (user typed bad date pattern), but this will give me null in two situations:

- user left field blank (which is ok in optional field)
- user provided date in incorrect format (never ok)

How to differentiate those scenerios to **"allow null (empty field), but if not empty, check date format"?**

Background: field is represented in POJO as `DateTime` and received in `@Controller` as `@RequestBody @Valid` becaus it is AJAX-posted.

Form POJO:

```
class MyForm {
@NotEmpty
private String name;

private DateTime expireOn; // JODA, optional but won't bad-format as null.

// getters, setters
}
```

Comment: please post your POJO

Comment: @Amrola Added form POJO

Comment: do you use hibernate validation as well ?

Comment: @amrola Yes. Maybe some misconfiguration gives me 400 Bad Request during Joda conversion? Should it default to error in binding result or to 400 code? (IllegalArgumentException thrown in my custom Spring converter)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use [@ScriptAssert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html) like the following :

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.validateExpireOn(_this.expireOn)")
 public class MyForm{


       public boolean validateExpireOn(Object obj){

            // here you check your expireOn Object if null or not , if not null check date format
            // this method should return boolean as if valid or not valid 
       }

        private DateTime expireOn;

}
```

Hope that Helps .

Comment: You must know that I have no chance to get to the controller and even JSR bean validation. The 400 Bad Request is trigerred probably by Spring converter, which launches before JSR validation

Comment: your question is : How to differentiate those scenerios to "allow null (empty field), but if not empty, check date format"?

Comment: Yes, and if user will type not-empty-with-bad-format date, then your @ScriptAssert will not even trigger, because JSR validation will not trigger, because Spring **coversion** will force 400 bad request